# how to open a text editor in eclipse 4.4 programmatically?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, text-editor, e4

I want to open a text editor in eclipse 4.4 programmatically. I've tried it using IDE class but it is not accessible in eclipse 4.4. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you asking about an e4 application (using the Application.e4xmi and no 3.x compatibility layer)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

e4 only has parts, not editors and views. It also doesn't have any predefined text editors.

Assuming you want to have several editor parts open at the same time you need to define a 'Part Descriptor' in the application model for the editor.

You then create a part from the descriptor using:

```java
@Inject
EPartService partService;


MPart part = partService.createPart("descriptor id");
```

You now need to add this to the application model. Usually this will be a child of an 'MPartStack':

```java
@Inject
EModelService modelService;
@Inject
MApplication app;

MPartStack editorStack = (MPartStack)modelService.find("part stack id", app);

editorStack.getChildren().add(part);
```

Finally show the part:

```java
partService.showPart(part, PartState.ACTIVATE);
```

The class you specify in the part descriptor for the editor will have to implement the text editor. You can use the JFace text editor classes but **not** the 'org.eclipse.ui.xxx' editor classes.

For a very simple text editor the `TextViewer` and `Document` classes are enough.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would we do it if it's not an e4 application but a simple eclipse plugin? I've tried using https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_open_an_editor_programmatically%3F but it doesnot work in eclipse 4.4..

Comment: If  the plugin is for an Eclipse installation (any release) that reference should work. Ask a new question with your code if you want more details on this.