# How to associate a perspective to a file type in Eclipse (e4)

Tags: eclipse, rcp, e4

I am trying to write an eclipse e4 plugin (not complete application) to view the contains of zip files. That means that I need a part with the filenames, and another part with the dump of the compressed file.

So far, I have seen that in eclipse (at least on e3) files are very coupled to editors, so seems like if eclipse 3, the way is using an editor like extending EditorPart

But I would like to work in e4, than checking here: [how to open a text editor in eclipse 4.4 programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28604569/how-to-open-a-text-editor-in-eclipse-4-4-programmatically) Greg states "e4 only has parts, not editors and views. It also doesn't have any predefined text editors." I understand that e3 mechanism is not the right way then...

So, the concrete question:

- How can I write an object that reacts to a file open operation and allows me to open a perspective?

Thanks for your answers.
Juan.

Comment: An e4 plugin to plug in to what? If this is plugging in to an 3.x compatibility mode RCP you should still use the e3 APIs. e4 provides absolutely nothing in this area.

Comment: Got it, thanks so quick answer.